# create dataset from 2 other datasets spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm a beginner to Spark and Scala.

I have two datasets, A and B as follows:

```
A
+---+----------+-----+---+
|_c0|       _c1|  _c2|_c3|
+---+----------+-----+---+
|  1|10.       |key1 | date1|
|  2|12.       | key2| date2|
+---+----------+-----+---+

B
+---+----------+-----+---+
|_c0|       _c4|  _c2|_c3|
+---+----------+-----+---+
|  1|2.        |key1 | date1|
|  2|3         | key5| date2|
+---+----------+-----+---+
```

Now I want to create a new dataset C that has a schema from columns C0, C1, C2, C3, and C4, where the new dataset would be matched based on values from C2 and C3 from dataset A and B, and use the values found in dataset B for C4, but would make those rows that don't match just be empty.

So in my example, I would have a new dataset `C` with

```
+---+----------+-----+---+-----
|c0 | _c1.     |_c2. |_c3|  c4
+---+----------+-----+---+-----
|  1|10.        |key1 | date1| 2
|  2|12.        |key2 | date1| null
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to do this?

EDIT - I tried doing a left join as follows:

```
var result = df1.join(df2, col("c2") === col("df2.c2") && col("c3") === col("df2.c3"), "left")
```

but its returning me more rows than whats in df1 by itself.

Comment: You are missing ```_``` in before ```column``` names - var result = df1.join(df2, col("_c2") === col("df2._c2") && col("_c3") === col("df2._c3"), "left"

Comment: Only syntax errors are there in the code you are trying, `df1.join(df2, df1("_c2") === df2(" _c2") && df1("_c3") === df2("_c3"), "left")` is giving not more than two rows. Paste your result and Update your question in case you need something else.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```scala
var result = df1.join(df2, df1("c2") === df2("c2") && df1("c3") === df2("c3"), "left")
```

> Please put column names as there in the respective data frames

If joining column names are same in both the left and right dataframe then you can use below variant too-

```scala
var result = df1.join(df2, Seq("c2", "c3"), "left")
```

Comment: whats the difference with your solution vs the one that i put in my edit, where i am still seeing more rows being returned than from the original dataframe? BTW, your solution is still yielding more results than the left data frame.